# Password hacking

Tags: java, c++, c

I have two files, a list of usernames and a list of passwords.  I need to write a program to check each user name with the list of passwords.  Then I need to go to a website and see if it logs in.  I am not very sure how to go about the comparing and how to simulate the program to log in the website enter the information.  Could you please help me out with this?  It's a homework problem.

Comment: Do the Java, C++ and C tags mean those are your options for implementing this?

Comment: What specifically will you do to check each username against the passwords? Or is logging in the check you're referring to?

Comment: yea ! i am not exactly sure what to use ..

Comment: log in check ! its for a website that is created by my TA.. we are supposed to log-in inside that

Comment: How do you need to compare usernames against passwords? Do you mean you have to combine every username with every password to try to log in?

Comment: I am given a file that contains a list of 100 users with weak passwords. Need to perform a brute-force dictionary attack to recover these passwords. I found a corpus of weak
passwords online need a program to check this

Comment: OK. Go through the list of users, and for each user, try to log in with each password from the weak passwords list? Is this correct?

Comment: yea thats what i need to do :(

Answer (score 6):

Regardless of the language you choose to implement this in, the basic idea is to simulate log-ins programatically. This can be done by logging in manually and looking at the HTTP headers, then sending "forged" headers programatically, changing the user/password fields.

Most log-ins will use POST and making a POST is not entirely straightforward. If you are allowed to use external libraries, you can try [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/). Simply set the appropriate headers and look at the response to check if your attempt was successful or not. If not, try again with a new combination.

In pseudo code:

```
bool simulate_login(user, password) :
    request = new request(url)
    request.set_method('POST')
    request.set_header('name', user)
    request.set_header('pass', password)

    response = request.fetch_reponse()
    return response.contains("Login successful")

success = []

foreach user:
    foreach password:
        if (simulate_login(user, password)):
            success.append((user, password))
            break
```

Comment: I am not very sure how to use cURL? how do i check using this ?

Comment: @Priya Check the link I provided on my answer

Comment: @Priya NullUserException hinted on this, but you might want to double check your class notes to make sure that they didn't already suggest a library or method to use for accessing the website. cURL will do the job fine, but it seems odd to give an assignment with so little direction.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to use java you can try with HtmlUnit (see: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) or if you are allowed Groovy you can go with http://www.gebish.org/

Here is the example from getting started guide that is relevant to your case:

```
public void login() throws Exception {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    // Get the first page
    final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://some_url");

    // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form, 
    // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
    final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("myform");

    final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("submitbutton");
    final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("userid");

    // Change the value of the text field
    textField.setValueAttribute("username");
    // Do similar for password and that's all

    // Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
    final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();

    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use java you can try with HtmlUnit (see: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) or if you are allowed Groovy you can go with http://www.gebish.org/

Here is the example from getting started guide that is relevant to your case:

public void login() throws Exception {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

```
// Get the first page
final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://some_url");

// Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form, 
// find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("myform");

final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("submitbutton");
final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("userid");

// Change the value of the text field
textField.setValueAttribute("username");
// Do similar for password and that's all

// Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
```

- ### List item